# Admin set to true not working on Rails after forgetting to register first the admin email in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, admin, rails-console

I have created a users' registration/signedup through Devise gem. To give a user an admin role I've added a new column in users table (giving the command in the terminal followed by rake db:migrate) named "admin" and set all to "false" by default:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false

  end

end
```

After this I've updated that same column to inform rails the email of the user with admin role followed by `rake db:migrate`:

```
class UpdateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    @u = User.find_by( email: 'administradora@gmail.com' )
    @u.update_attribute :admin, true

  end

end
```

The problem is that I forgot to register first that particular user in the app and I got an error. I went back this last migration and I register that user in the app and after that I added the above lines inside the change method and I got no more error. However the app is not considering this particular email as an admin and when I search in the db console that particular user is set to "false" for the admin column. I don't know how to solve it.

- Is it possible to change the "false" value directly in the console using SQL Data Manipulation Language such as `Update users set admin = true (...)`?
- If I try to do again an UpdateUsers to add a new email it complaints with a "conflict" due an already existent UpdateUsers migration. How do we add new users with admin role set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `rake db:migrate` a second time (after having run it once to apply the `UpdateUsers` migration), it will not run the script within as it is considered that the migration is already applied.

You will have to rollback the migration, and apply it again with the following steps:

```
> rake db:rollback
> rake db:migrate
```

There is a shortcut for doing both of these together:

```
> rake db:migrate:redo
```

A useful tip here is to use `rake db:migrate:status` to view which migrations have been applied at any given time.

Read up http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling-back for more info about this.

To the more specific questions about adding admin users:

I usually do it directly from the console, as it is a one time setup.

```
$ rails console
> u = User.find_by( email: 'administradora@gmail.com' )
> @u.update_attribute :admin, true
```

You could do it directly in the database as well by running a sql query.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you so much! It's working! To be honest I am scare to experiment commands in Rails because I'm always having errors that I have no idea what they are! Thanks a million!!!

Comment: Don't be scared to experiment as it is only code, not someone's life :-) Check out this talk by Glenn Vanderburg; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NP9AIUT9nos that talk gave me a lot of freedom in making mistakes while coding.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create admins/users is to user the seed.rb file in the "db" directory.

Here's what I have, but you can alter.

```
User.destroy_all

frank = User.new
frank.email = "blahblah@gmail.com"
frank.password = "password"
frank.password_confirmation = "password"
frank.admin = "true"
frank.save!
```

Then in command prompt run

```
rake db:seed
```

Only keep in the "User.destroy_all" if you want to delete all users.  Take that out if you don't.  I'm not totally sure on the "true", it might not need quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about this "seed" file. I solved with the rollback migration function! Thanks a million!!!

Comment: I tried to upvote, but apparently I don't have privileges for that :| sorry thanks

Comment: Hah, no worries.  Good luck!